# How to Determine the Angle of Rotation for a Point

Tags: algorithm, math, rotation, angle

I have 2 points in an x, y plane. I want to rotate one point onto the other point by rotating it about the z-axis.

How can I find the angle to rotate one point onto the other?

Comment: What language are you working with? Provide your hypothetical code.

Comment: Are the two points coplanar such that a z-axis rotation would exactly align them?

Comment: It's in Python. However, the points are provided by software that does not allow me to manipulate the verts via an API call. I have to find the angle and then do a rotation. That's why I left the language out of the question. Just looking for a higher level approach.

Comment: @templatetypedef yes

Comment: @user2970916: I assume you mean "rotate about the origin" as there is no z-axis in a 2D plane?

Comment: The rotation occurs in a 2D plane, but it goes about the origin which can be represented by a  z axis.

Comment: Maybe a sketch can help clarify things.

Comment: I would love to put a sketch, however I can't see images on SO from my work computer. So, I would not know if the sketch looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `sin` of this angle is `[a, b] / (abs(a) * abs(b))` and its `cos` is `(a, b) / (abs(a) * abs(b))`, where `[a, b]` is a cross product of `a` and `b`, `(a, b)` is a scalar product and `abs(x)` is the length of the vector `x`. It is pretty easy to find an angle given its `sin` and `cos`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best thing is to get the angles from horizontal for the two points and then take the difference.

```
angle_1 = atan2( y_1, x_1 );
angle_2 = atan2( y_2, x_2 );

rotation_angle = angle_1-angle_2;
```